# Matplotlib color scales that are suitable for printing

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot

Is there an existing color map that can be easily applied to make a line plot visible on a grayscale medium (e.g. a paper printed in black and white) by modifying the way the line is drawn (e.g. black full line, black dashed line, gray full line, etc.)?

The gray color scale is a good start but it doesn't cut it: when I have more than 4 series on the same plot it's hard to distinguish once printed, and also it colors one series as white (making it invisible unless I change the background to something else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vary the linestyles as shown [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/line_styles_reference.html) and use different markers as shown [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html).
Finally, I would suggest you look at [cyclers](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html) to loop over different colors, linestyles and markers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am using it through Pandas, so it was even easier because it was a matter of providing a style argument, but you pointed me towards the right direction because I had no idea this existed. My final bit of code looked like this:

`merged1.plot.line(cmap='Dark2', style=['-', '--', ':', '-.'])`